# Optionally open folder in new window in vista using keyboard key

Tags: windows-vista

In XP, to ensure a folder opened in a new window, I held down CTRL when I opened (by mouse or keyboard) the folder.

This action is so ingrained to me, I pretty much don't even realise I'm doing it at a conscious level.

Unfortunately, this action apparently hasn't made it to Vista. Is there a new way to do this, or am I just missing something obvious?

**EDIT** Looks like not possible in Vista, but returned in Win7. Answer selected as it mentioned a keyboard alternative in Ctrl+N.

Comment: I always thought holding Shift would do that.

Comment: Only if you have multiple folders selected, and all but the first folder will

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable it to always open in a new window, but don't know if you want that.

[image: open in a new window]

Or you can use CTRL + N to open a new Window or right click the folder you want to open in a new window and select "Open".

Comment: Not exactly the required functionality, but thanks nonetheless

Answer (score 3):

I realize it's probably not the most useful answer, but in case you're considering upgrading, the "hold down CTRL while opening a folder to open it in a new window"-feature is back in Windows 7.

Comment: brilliant, glad to hear it. I have an upgrade at home, but haven't had the time to install it

Comment: +1 since I didn't know this about Windows 7.  I was almost trained to use CTRL+N since moving to Vista, now I can go back to CTRL+Click heaven.  Thanks!  :-)